# Waitress Warning 434 HTTPTooManyRequests

Tags: warnings, waitress

I receive the warning 434
I use

```
waitress.serve(app=falcon_app, host="0.0.0.0", port=7021, threads=100)
```

and i get the following warning:

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\API\lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py:434: DeprecatedWarning: Calls to HTTPTooManyRequests.init(...) with positional args are deprecated. Please specify them as keyword arguments instead.
app_iter = self.channel.server.application(environ, start_response)

Can you tell me how to fix it?

I have a falcon API and i use waitress as server. some times i get the warning 434 and some times it's working and i don't know how to fix it